# Making array for click function in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, arraylist, click

in my web i have many button that javascript for managing click function. Every button click has class for initial each of them. here the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data1").click(function(){
        $("#line").val("1");
        $("#pkategori").val("-Kategori Produk-");
        $("#pname").val("-Nama Produk-");
        $("#pnumber").val("");
        $("#seri").val("");
        $("#quantity").val("");
        $("#ok").hide();
        $("#cancel").hide();
        $("#tnposisi").hide();
        $("#nposisi").hide();
        $("#tketp").hide();
        $("#ketp").hide();
        $("#tpjumlah").hide();
        $("#pjumlah").hide();
        $("#editsave").hide();
        $("#editcancel").hide();
        $("#input").hide();
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#status").html("");
    });
});
```

for my current web, i make this one by one until `$(".data160").click(function()`. it will be long code and not effective. My problem, How tomake this a simple code?

Answer (score 1):

separate it with several functions:

1、val and html together

2、hide together, you can create a function like this

```
    function hideEl(el){
      $('#'+el).hide();

    }
   var arrEls = ['pname','apple','msn'...];
   $(arrEls).each(function(key,value){
      hideEl(value);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all the buttons the same class, and use data attributes for the different features.

```
<button class="data" data-line="1" data-kategory="-Kategori Produk-" data-name="-Nama Produk-">
```

Then write:

```
$(".data").click(function(){
    $("#line").val($(this).data("line"));
    $("#pkategori").val($(this).data("kategori"));
    $("#pname").val($(this).data("name"));
    $("#pnumber,#seri,#quantity").val("");
    $("#ok,#cancel,#tnposisi,#nposisi,#tketp,#ketp,#tpjumlah,#pjumlah,#editsave,#editcancel,#input,#loading").hide();
    $("#status").html("");
});
```

To handle them all at once.